# Loop to create array + loop increment?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I wanted to create a function which gets called upon-page load and generates a graph based on what user inputs (multiple datasets, using *chart.js*).

Decided to rely on prompt() for initial testing, but soon ran into a problem.

```
function defineDatasets(itt){
    for(i=0; i<itt; i++){
        var dataSet+i=[]; // <--- Does not result in a array called "dataSet0[], ..." etc
    }
}
```

So my question is, if and how could this be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're trying to suffix your arrays with an index, why not just make an array of arrays? Also be sure to define your `dataSet` outside the function scope:

```
let dataSet = [];

function defineDatasets(itt) {
    for(var i = 0; i < itt; i++) {
        dataSet.push([]);
    }
}

console.log(dataSet[0]); // []
```

Now instead of referencing these arrays with `dataSetN`, you can do `dataSet[N]`, where `N` is the Nth dataSet index.

Comment: It might be beneficial to `dataSet = [];` before the `for` loop so that multiple calls to `defineDatasets()` does not append more empty arrays to `dataSet` if it's already been initialized.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - True. Alternatively, changing `dataSet.push([])` to `dataSet[i] = []` would mitigate this issue.

Comment: That'd actually be even worse. Consider `defineDatasets(20); /* do stuff with dataSet... */ defineDatasets(10); /* expect dataSet.length === 10, but it's actually still 20 */`